# How to set value inside input tag of web Page present inside web View?

Tags: android, webview

I want to auto populate the data inside cell of table but not getting access of it my HTML Code is as follows:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="innertd">
            <table border-collapse="collapse" class="inner" id="tbl" cellspacing="2" border="1">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Consumer No</td>
                             <td><input class="number-only" id="consumerNo" style="width:120px;" oratype="string;precision:254" oraerrorelement="consumerNo" tabindex="5" type="text"></td>                           
                        </tr> 
                </thead>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And Android Code is as follows:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            final String consumerNumber = "1234";

            final String JSSetAccountId = "javascript:" +
                    "document.getElementById('consumerNo').value = '" + consumerNumber + "'";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                view.evaluateJavascript(JSSetAccountId, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    }
                });
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(JSSetAccountId);
            }
            dismissLoadingDialog();

        }
    }
```

Please, Help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebView wb;
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web1.html");
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
        final String consumerNumber = "1234";
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('consumerNo').value = '"+consumerNo+"';})()");

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply, but I am not using any Static URL so this solution is not work for me!
This line throws an error
 "[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:  " +
                        "var consumerNo= document.getElementById('consumerNo'); " +
                        "consumerNo.value = '"+consumerNo+"'; " +
                        "consumerNo.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) ",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having a look at the [jsoup](https://jsoup.org) library. It allows for parsing and manipulating of HTML fetched either from a file or a URL.
This section of the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) shows a way to target a specific element in HTML.
You can remove HTML displayed, append items, replace items, change attributes, it's quite powerful. Then just load the parsed HTML into a WebView when you've made the changes you want to.